# How can i allow all in nginx?

Tags: nginx

My website is only accessible on a certain ip address so i only can have access to it if i'm in that machine or a connection towards it

I tried adding Nginx allow all to the config but it's still not working

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain;

  #Specify a charset
  charset utf-8;

  location  /api {
    satisfy any;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass          http://192.168.226.264:8080;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
    allow all;
  }

  location / {
    root /Users/administrator/Documents
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

I get this :

```
This site can’t be reached. 
domain’s server IP address could not be found
```

What do i need to add to make the website accessible by all ip addresses

Comment: Please don't paste code as images. Is this a complete config?

Comment: Sorry, here is it as code. I updated it with the whole config for that domain

Comment: same problem here even though i add the allow all, only the local machine has access to the website

Comment: Are you running it native or in a container?

Comment: @DánielBencze if i understand your question well, i'm running it native and not in a container like docker

Comment: @Shubh the firewall on the machine where i configured nginx is turned off

Comment: @koreangirl, In that case, it's most likely that you are exposing the private address instead of the public one. You can check what's your public IP by running this for example `curl https://ipinfo.io/ip` once you have it, try to expose it on that ip instead of what you have now.

Comment: @DánielBencze where do i expose it? in the proxy pass?

Comment: @koreangirl, No, so your server name is currently `domain` which is what nginx will bind to, so change `domain` to your public or private address or your domain name. So if your domain name is `mywebsite.com` than your `server_name` variable in the top will be `mywebsite.com`

Comment: @DánielBencze well i only put domain to mean domain but in my real config i'm putting new.domain.se

Comment: On the server where you are running nginx, what does `hostname` command comes back with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203123/discussion-between-koreangirl-and-daniel-bencze).

Answer (score -1):

Try whether you domain is getting resolved using "whois" command from the terminal where you have installed the nginx server :

```
whois domainname
```

You have mentioned a `"server_name domain"` , is that domain resolvable from your terminal ?

Comment: can you be specific about the error you get , you get "Access Denied" / "connection refused" ?

Comment: i get This site can’t be reached. domain’s server IP address could not be found.

Comment: Then did you telnet the server with the port and try whether you can access the machine from where the nginx is installed .

Comment: @redhatvicky i can access the website from the machine where nginx is installed but not from other connections

Comment: I dint understand the second part where you are trying to access through "other connections" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203121/discussion-between-redhatvicky-and-koreangirl).

Comment: @redhatvicky when i do telnet domain 80, it get connected as long as i'm in the same machine... but once i try to do it from another machine, then i get domain: nodename nor servname provided, or not known